# Plotting the ROC curve of K-fold Cross Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, roc

I am working with an imbalanced dataset. I have applied SMOTE Algorithm to balance the dataset after splitting the dataset into test and training set before applying ML models. I want to apply cross-validation and plot the ROC curves of each folds showing the AUC of each fold and also display the mean of the AUCs in the plot. I named the resampled training set variables as X_train_res and y_train_res and following is the code:

```
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)
classifier = SVC(kernel='sigmoid',probability=True,random_state=0)

tprs = []
aucs = []
mean_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
i = 0
for train, test in cv.split(X_train_res, y_train_res):
    probas_ = classifier.fit(X_train_res[train], y_train_res[train]).predict_proba(X_train_res[test])
    # Compute ROC curve and area the curve
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_train_res[test], probas_[:, 1])
    tprs.append(interp(mean_fpr, fpr, tpr))
    tprs[-1][0] = 0.0
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)
    plt.plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.3,
             label='ROC fold %d (AUC = %0.2f)' % (i, roc_auc))

    i += 1
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], linestyle='--', lw=2, color='r',
         label='Chance', alpha=.8)

mean_tpr = np.mean(tprs, axis=0)
mean_tpr[-1] = 1.0
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)
std_auc = np.std(aucs)
plt.plot(mean_fpr, mean_tpr, color='b',
         label=r'Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f $\pm$ %0.2f)' % (mean_auc, std_auc),
         lw=2, alpha=.8)

std_tpr = np.std(tprs, axis=0)
tprs_upper = np.minimum(mean_tpr + std_tpr, 1)
tprs_lower = np.maximum(mean_tpr - std_tpr, 0)
plt.fill_between(mean_fpr, tprs_lower, tprs_upper, color='grey', alpha=.2,
                 label=r'$\pm$ 1 std. dev.')

plt.xlim([-0.01, 1.01])
plt.ylim([-0.01, 1.01])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate',fontsize=18)
plt.title('Cross-Validation ROC of SVM',fontsize=18)
plt.legend(loc="lower right", prop={'size': 15})
plt.show()
```

following is the output:

[image]

Please tell me whether the code is correct for plotting ROC curve for the cross-validation or not.

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing the whole correct code (as a solution to your post)? I am facing some issues with smote + roc curves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that I do not clearly understand cross-validation. In the for loop range, I have passed the training sets of X and y variables. Does cross-validation work like this?

Leaving SMOTE and the imbalance issue aside, which are not included in your code, your procedure looks correct.

In more detail, for each one of your `n_splits=10`:

- you create `train` and `test` folds
- you fit the model using the `train` fold:

  ```
  classifier.fit(X_train_res[train], y_train_res[train])
  ```
- and then you predict probabilities using the `test` fold:

  ```
  predict_proba(X_train_res[test])
  ```

This is exactly the idea behind cross-validation.

So, since you have `n_splits=10`, you get 10 ROC curves and respective AUC values (and their average), exactly as expected.

**However**:

The need for (SMOTE) upsampling due to the class imbalance changes the correct procedure, and turns your overall process **incorrect**: you should **not** upsample your initial dataset; instead, you need to incorporate the upsampling procedure into the CV process.

So, the correct procedure here for each one of your `n_splits` becomes (notice that starting with a stratified CV split, as you have done, becomes essential in class imbalance cases):

- create `train` and `test` folds
- upsample your `train` fold with SMOTE
- fit the model using the upsampled `train` fold
- predict probabilities using the `test` fold (not upsampled)

For details regarding the rationale, please see own answer in the Data Science SE thread [Why you shouldn't upsample before cross validation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/82073/why-you-shouldnt-upsample-before-cross-validation).